# How can you edit the brightness of images in PyGame?

Tags: python-2.7, opengl, pygame

I'm trying to make an OpenGL in python/pygame but I don't know how to add shadow. I don't want to make a lot of darker images for my game. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no expert in Python but you could try:

**Multiply the color** of the image by a value like `0.1, 0.2, 0.3 (anything less that 1)` which will give you a very dark texture. This would be the easiest method as it involves just reducing the color values of that texture.

Or you could try a more complex method such as *drawing a **transparent black quad*** over the original image to give it the illusion of being in a shadow.